# GenericADOException when select from table with big amount of entries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fluent-nhibernate

I get **GenericADOException Timeout expired** exception when `select` request performing in my app and in parallel with them `insert` performing for the same table. There are over 1000000 entries in this table. I select enteties to look at them meanwhile new enteties are adding to DB.

Session opened, commited and closed by entry for sure for `insert`.

I have indexes for all necessary columns. I did `reorganize` for them just in case it did't help.

Select Request looks like:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 ... FROM table WHERE fk = some_value
```

Exception occurs with Fluent NHibernate because sometimes request take too much time to complete. This error occurs from time to time but is really annoying.

I use `IQueryable` for `select`.

How else can I improve performance in my case?

Actural queries:

```
    INSERT INTO EVENT_LOG 
    (full_name, event_date, event, description, full_description_zipped, t_number) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); 
    select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    select eventlogen0_.event_ID as event1_22_, eventlogen0_.full_name 
    as full2_22_, eventlogen0_.event_date as event3_22_, eventlogen0_.event as event22_, 
    eventlogen0_.description as descript5_22_, eventlogen0_.full_description_zipped as full6_22_,
    eventlogen0_.t_number as t7_22_ 
    from EVENT_LOG eventlogen0_ 
    where eventlogen0_.t_number=?
    order by eventlogen0_.event_ID desc
```

Table's sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EVENT_LOG] (
    [event_ID]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [full_name]      NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    [event_date]     DATETIME         CONSTRAINT [DF_EVENT_LOG_event_date] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [event]          NVARCHAR (150)   NOT NULL,
    [transaction_ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [description]    NVARCHAR (4000)  NULL,
    [t_number]       NVARCHAR (20)    NULL,
    [full_description_zipped] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EVENT_LOG] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([event_ID] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NX_EVENT_LOG_T_NUMBER]
ON [dbo].[EVENT_LOG]([t_number] ASC) 
INCLUDE ([event_ID]);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NX_EVENT_LOG_EVENT_DATE]
    ON [dbo].[EVENT_LOG]([event_date] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NX_EVENT_LOG_EVENT]
    ON [dbo].[EVENT_LOG]([event] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DATE_EVENT_TNUMBER]
    ON [dbo].[EVENT_LOG]([event_date] ASC, [event] ASC, [t_number] ASC);
```

Execution plan for select (sorry for my non-english studio)
[image]

Comment: Downvote reason: Critical details are missing. Performance tuning requires knowledge of the tables involved, the queries involved, and the execution plans. We have none of these.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry, fixed this

Answer (score 0):

1000000 записей достаточно много, когда они отсылаются клиенту.
Учитывая, что таблица достаточно толстая (много полей больших размеров), то рекомендую просто увеличить тайм-аут запроса к серверу в клиентском коде.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx